# How to handle longjmp case of C in Rust?

Tags: c, rust

I am writing a prewritten code in C to Rust . So in that there's a condition that's handled by longjmp in c but i don't know how to handle it in rust.

```
if (pointer_to_struct->count_of_something < (count << 10)){ 
    longjmp(*(pointer_to_struct->xyz), MACRO);
}
```

Comment: `setjmp` and `longjmp` are usually a bad idea in C. Which is why few other languages have anything like that.

Comment: Don't translate between lines of code. Extract the design of the program and then rewrite from the design in your target language. What's the _declarative description_ of your code? What does it _do_? Not _how does it do it_?

Comment: As for translating your C code to Rust (or, really, any other language) my general recommendation is ***don't do that***. Instead take the requirements, limitations, analysis and design and *reimplement* it, from scratch. Direct translations, no matter if it's programming languages, written languages or spoken languages, almost never turn out well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude any alternative to consume the stack of a recursive function without longjmp?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes, change algorithm from recursive to iterative. Or use a design that doesn't require states leading to a `longjmp` call (there are plenty of problems that can happen with `longjmp`, not only the commonly noted "spaghetti" code syndrome).

Comment: @DavidRanieri By returning an error down the stack?

Comment: Switching from recursive to iterative requires using dynamic memory in a lot of cases ... and  longjmp is in fact the only way to consume the stack without writing spaghetti code

Comment: @IanAbbott care to explain?

Comment: @DavidRanieri If the recursive call returns an error then return an error. Rust's `Result` type would be a good fit for that approach.

Comment: Returning from a recursive function and consume the stack produced by a recursive function are different things

Comment: @DavidRanieri `longjmp()` **is** "spaghetti code" and its use to bail out of recursion is indicative of unclean determination of when to halt recursion.  If memory use is a concern, stack usage is usually much more constraining than dynamic memory use.  Running out of stack can rarely be handled cleanly, whereas running out of dynamic memory is directly apparent as `malloc()` *et al* will return `NULL`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree, but malloc is not always the best option (i.e. embedded programming)

Comment: And running out of stack is not relevant here ... I'm asking for alternatives to longjmp in the typical case where you want to unwind the stack

Comment: @AndrewHenle checking `NULL` in malloc et. al. is a pretty poor way to do it, for one some systems will allow overcommitting memory, and for the other you'll get substantially degraded performance and other memory-consumption-induced issues long before your allocator will give up (ofc not an issue if you're writing a specific known system which doesn't have those as problems)

Comment: @Cubic If you have any reliability standards at all, you disable memory overcommit and provision your systems with enough memory.  And don't let knuckleheads log on and fire up Eclipse...

Comment: @DavidRanieri Rust has `std::panic::catch_unwind` but it might not work. See [Item 18: Don't panic - Effective Rust](https://www.lurklurk.org/effective-rust/panic.html).

Comment: @DavidRanieri Sometimes you have to do what you have to do despite clean code standards.  `longjmp()` to simply unwind a deep stack might be safe, depending on what the code being skipped over would otherwise do.  I'd comment the heck out of the code involved, though, making sure to note the calls that might be jumped over and never return.  In this case, I'd make sure it's a pure C stack being jumped over, and `longjmp()` restrictions are all adhered to.  No Ruby-like abuse.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately I have 0 idea of Rust, It was more a question about C. OP sorry for the off topic

Comment: @DavidRanieri Well in C, the alternative to using `longjmp()` is to pretend it doesn't exist and deal with it the hard way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give little context in your question, but I'll try an answer anyway.

In C, `longjmp()` is used to unwind a deeply nested call stack when other approaches of doing so are impractical. It is hard to use correctly, but given the lack of other ways to unwind the stack in C it's sometimes the least of all evils.

In Rust, the most idiomatic way to unwind a stack is making all functions involved in the call stack return `Result<...>`, using the question mark operator `?` for all calls and returning `Err(...)` when you want to unwind. This results in all functions returning normally and destructors being called.

The closest Rust has to `set_jmp()` and `long_jmp()` is [`catch_unwind()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) and [`panic!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html). These functions are not meant to be used as general flow control mechanisms. You can only catch "unwinding panics", which are sometimes not available (e.g. in embedded environments). If you can avoid it, don't use `catch_unwind()`, and use proper error handling instead.